# AngularFire2: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function using rxjs 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, angularfire2

We're using AngularFire2's AngularFireStorage to access our Firebase storage bucket:

```
this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
```

Unfortunately, lately this has started to throw an error:

```
polyfills.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at handler (index.esm.js:3126)
at index.esm.js:3273
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
at o (polyfills.js:3)
at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
at p (polyfills.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.v (polyfills.js:2)
```

This issue has been posted many times, and all answers point to upgrading to rxjs6 including rxjs-compat. Unfortunately I have done this already quite some time ago. We are currently using rjxs@6.5.3

- Angular:5.0.3
- Firebase:7.2.1
- AngularFire:5.2.1
- Ionic:3.9.5
- Cordova:9.0.0
- rxjs:6.5.3
- rxjs-compat:6.5.3
- typescript:3.6.4

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downgrading firebase to 6.6.2